# chrome extension manifest v2 and onclick events in a div element

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm in the process of converting a chrome extension from manifest v1 to manifest v2.

I've extracted most of the javascript code from the html files and put it in separate .js files.

I've a problem with a div element in a popup.

The current code in popup.html is:

```
  <div onclick="PopupClick('SHOW')" id="blue">Show</div>
```

Apparently onclick="" is not allowed in html since v2, but how to replace it,
so that the user can click on the div and a function is executed?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It clearly states the alternative: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1

Answer (score 6):

*popup.html:*

```
 <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <div id="blue">Show</div>
```

*popup.js:*

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {  
 document.getElementById("blue").addEventListener('click',
 clickHandler); }); 

function clickHandler(e) {   PopupClick('SHOW'); }

 function PopupClick(str) {
   //Do your thing here 
}
```

Like Rob W said, it's clear in http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1

I actually faced this problem and this code help me move from manifest v1 to v2.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe events? Include something like `<script src="js/my_script.js">` in head of your `popup.html` and then paste code in that js file.

```
var blueDiv = document.getElementById("blue");
    blueDiv.addEventListener("click", function(){
        PopupClick("SHOW");
    }, false);
```

Or some specifics of your app doesn't allow you to do this? Or i don't understand the problem.